# Git & CI: How to tag if build passes/revert commit if fails?

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration

I am trying to setup jenkins for continuous integration with my python repo.  I have everything working in that it will poll for updates to the repo and then run nosetests and either succeed or fail depending on the result of the tests. If the tests pass, I want it to tag the commits from the latest push with build number ("v1.0.$BUILD_NUMBER").  If the tests fail, I want it to revert to the previous tag.

What is the proper way to tag the commits from the latest push?
What is the proper way to revert if it fails?

I am getting confused on subtleties of annotated vs lightweight tags and revert vs reset.  Especially the latter can really screw things up if used incorrectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`revert` creates a new commit that includes the inverse content to the content of the commit you're revert.

The git repo before:

```
A---B---C
```

`git revert C`

The git repo after:

```
A---B---C---C'
```

C' is an inverse commit to C.

`reset` sets a new value (SHA) to a branch (like it was a pointer). Do neither produce nor deletes a commit. Resetting a branch that is shared between several developers is considered as a "brutal" behavior and will put your co-developers in a problematic state so if they aren't aware of the `reset` they might merge the commit (you wanted to remove) again.

The git repo before (current branch is master):

```
A---B---C
         \
          master
```

`git reset B`

The git repo after:

```
A---B---C
     \
      master
```

The master branch now points to commit B. Commit C is there but nothing points to it, so it will be garbage collected probably.

From [AlBlue’s Blog](http://alblue.bandlem.com/2011/04/git-tip-of-week-tags.html)

> An `annotated tag` creates an additional tag object in the Git repository, which allows you to store information associated with the tag itself. This may include release notes, the meta-information about the release, and optionally a signature to verify the authenticity of the commit to which it points.

VS

A `lightweight tag` holds nothing except of the SHA of the commit it was stacked to.

Comment: So if I wanted to undo a commit that is causing nosetests to fail it would be safer to use revert yes?

Comment: Yes, it is safer.

However, reverting a not last commit could involve resolving conflicts, so it couldn't be done automatically.

Comment: Yea I want it to be done automatically.  If I do reset --hard, commit C would still exist, its just the HEAD will point to B correct?

Comment: You're right. Be aware that it will put the local copies of the branch in the diverged state for all user that have that branch locally in their environments. That might lead to their mistake - trying to merge commit C back into the branch.

Comment: But if they do a pull before they start working on it again they would be fine right?  I'm going to set it up that there  is notification for if tests pass or fail so they should know right away.

Comment: I'd advise you to test that on you private branch/env (using 2 separate clones) before you roll that solution for all repo users.
The test scenario should be: 
 1. Reset and push a branch from clone A.
 2. Pull from clone B.
I guess whether pull fail or it will merge the problematic commit back.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be much easier for everyone if you would configure jenkins to merge with master before the build and test. Then, if tests pass, jenkins can push the result to master. If tests fail, there is nothing to revert.

Comment: Whats the point of merging with master before tests pass?  The point is to roll back the dev branch if the tests fail.

Comment: It is ok to merge with master in Jenkins because the merge exists only in the Jenkins workspace. Then you configure a post-build step to push the result of the merge into some git repo where it will become visible to everyone. (Git plugin provides that post build step)

Comment: And, the post-build task to push will not run if the build is unstable or failed, so there is no need to revert anything.

Comment: You should read the section titled "Using Git, Jenkins and pre-build branch merging" in https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin